# How to select rows based on two column values?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table structured somewhat like this:

```
type    name    value
=====================
1       item1    1
1       item2    20
2       item3    0
3       item4    5
3       item5    2
3       item6    50
```

I need to write a query that returns the lowest valued item of each type, sorted by the value. So the result should be:

```
type    name    value
=====================
2       item3    0
1       item1    1
3       item5    2
```

I can get this to work, but it's looking really, really ugly right now. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: *"I can get this to work"* ... Can you show us that code, then? It's okay if it's a disaster, but people need a baseline :)

Comment: Yeah, if you show code -- its easier for us to help make it look better so we don't have to try and re-write what you've already written..

Comment: @rdlowrey - well, my current code selects *all* the rows, and then in php (so after the query) I store all the rows in an array, sort them by the "value" value, then loop through and find the row for each type with the lowest "value" value. I was hoping all that could be done in the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a "greatest-n-per-group" query (under that tag on SO you will find many similar questions). (I know you want the "lowest-n-per-group", but it's the same problem).

Usually, you would be able to do:

```
SELECT type, MIN(value)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY type
```

But this won't work if you also want the `name` corresponding to the `MIN(value)`.

To retrieve the minimum `value` per `type` and *also* the corresponding row, you join your table to itself within `type` (the `GROUP BY`) variable, and with a sorting condition on `value` (the `MIN`) variable:

```
SELECT t1.type, t1.name, t1.value
FROM mytable t1
LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.type = t2.type AND t1.value > t2.value
WHERE t2.value IS NULL
```

Note :

- we `LEFT JOIN` `mytable` *to itself*, restricting the join such that all the `type`s are the same. This will produce a table with every combination of values for each type.
- we add a condition to the `LEFT JOIN` to restrict the combinations of values such that `t1.value > t2.value`. So now we have a table with every combination of values within each type, but t1's is bigger than t2's
- since this is a `LEFT JOIN`, if there is a `t1.value` for which there is *no smaller* `t2.value`, the corresponding `t2` columns will be NULL. But this is *precisely* the smallest `t1.value` for that type!
- Add a `WHERE t2.value IS NULL` condition in to pick out exactly these rows.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT type, name, MIN(value) as value FROM table GROUP BY type`

Comment: This won't necessarily pick the `name` that corresponds to `MIN(value)` for each `type`.

Comment: Right, that was just a quick example. +1 to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Edit 3:
Here are the queries reworked grouping by type instead of name.

`select type, name, min(value) from (select, type, name, value from Table order by value asc) group by type`

This one may work, but I'm not sure. See below. Man, what a mess.

`select type, name, min(value) from Table group by type order by value asc`

Edit 2:
Sorry, I read the question wrong. You can ignore this answer

---

I need to double check this. Can't remember if the order by will make it so the correct type will be selected.

`select type, name, min(value) from Table group by name order by value asc`

Edit:
I tested a similar query on one of my datasets and it seemed to work. But I can't say for sure because I just read that order by happens after group by.

So an alternative would be this then:

`select type, name, min(value) from (select, type, name, value from Table order by value asc) group by name`